# Cleaner Alternative to Extensive Pattern Matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, boolean-logic

Right now, I have some code that essentially works like this:

```
data Expression 
    = Literal Bool 
    | Variable String
    | Not Expression 
    | Or Expression Expression 
    | And Expression Expression
    deriving Eq

simplify :: Expression -> Expression
simplify (Literal b) = Literal b
simplify (Variable s) = Variable s
simplify (Not e) = case simplify e of
    (Literal b) -> Literal (not b)
    e'          -> Not e'
simplify (And a b) = case (simplify a, simplify b) of
    (Literal False, _) -> Literal False
    (_, Literal False) -> Literal False
    (a', b')           -> And a' b'
simplify (Or a b) = case (simplify a, simplify b) of
    (Literal True, _) -> Literal True
    (_, Literal True) -> Literal True
    (a', b')          -> Or a' b'
```

And many more such patterns regarding all the ways one can simplify a boolean expression. As I add more operators and rules however, this grows immensely and feels.. clunky. Especially so since some rules need to be added twice to account for commutativity.

How can I nicely refactor lots and lots of patterns of which some (most, I'd say) are even symmetrical (take the And and Or patterns for example)?

Right now, adding a rule to simplify `And (Variable "x") (Not (Variable "x"))` to `Literal False` requires me to add two nested rules, which is all but optimal.

Comment: Try to write your datatype as a GADT. This will not really make it cleaner but it will give you more type safety. Then you can still apply any of  the solutions below.

Comment: In what way would I benefit from using GADTs here?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I assumed an expression like `Not (Variable "True")` would not typecheck, but rethinking it over, the _Variable String_ constructor doesn't return soemthing special. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One thing you can do is simplify as you construct, rather than first constructing then repeatedly destructing. So:

```
module Simple (Expression, true, false, var, not, or, and) where

import Prelude hiding (not, or, and)

data Expression
    = Literal Bool
    | Variable String
    | Not Expression
    | Or Expression Expression
    | And Expression Expression
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

true = Literal True
false = Literal False
var = Variable

not (Literal True) = false
not (Literal False) = true
not x = Not x

or (Literal True) _ = true
or _ (Literal True) = true
or x y = Or x y

and (Literal False) _ = false
and _ (Literal False) = false
and x y = And x y
```

We can try it out in ghci:

```
> and (var "x") (and (var "y") false)
Literal False
```

Note that the constructors are not exported: this ensures that folks constructing one of these can't avoid the simplification process. Actually, this may be a drawback; occasionally it is nice to see the "full" form. A standard approach to dealing with this is to make the exported smart constructors part of a type-class; you can either use them to build a "full" form or a "simplified" way. To avoid having to define the type twice, we could either use a newtype or a phantom parameter; I'll elect for the latter here to reduce the noise in pattern-matching.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
module Simple (Format(..), true, false, var, not, or, and) where

import Prelude hiding (not, or, and)

data Format = Explicit | Simplified

data Expression (a :: Format)
    = Literal Bool
    | Variable String
    | Not (Expression a)
    | Or (Expression a) (Expression a)
    | And (Expression a) (Expression a)
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

class Expr e where
    true, false :: e
    var :: String -> e
    not :: e -> e
    or, and :: e -> e -> e

instance Expr (Expression Explicit) where
    true = Literal True
    false = Literal False
    var = Variable
    not = Not
    or = Or
    and = And

instance Expr (Expression Simplified) where
    true = Literal True
    false = Literal False
    var = Variable

    not (Literal True) = false
    not (Literal False) = true
    not x = Not x

    or (Literal True) _ = true
    or _ (Literal True) = true
    or x y = Or x y

    and (Literal False) _ = false
    and _ (Literal False) = false
    and x y = And x y
```

Now in ghci we can "run" the same term in two different ways:

```
> :set -XDataKinds
> and (var "x") (and (var "y") false) :: Expression Explicit
And (Variable "x") (And (Variable "y") (Literal False))
> and (var "x") (and (var "y") false) :: Expression Simplified
Literal False
```

You might want to add more rules later; for example, maybe you want:

```
and (Variable x) (Not (Variable y)) | x == y = false
and (Not (Variable x)) (Variable y) | x == y = false
```

Having to repeat both "orders" of patterns is a bit annoying. We should abstract over that! The data declaration and classes will be the same, but we'll add the helper function `eitherOrder` and use it in the definitions of `and` and `or`. Here's a more complete set of simplifications using this idea (and our final version of the module):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
module Simple (Format(..), true, false, var, not, or, and) where

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Monoid
import Prelude hiding (not, or, and)
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

data Format = Explicit | Simplified

data Expression (a :: Format)
    = Literal Bool
    | Variable String
    | Not (Expression a)
    | Or (Expression a) (Expression a)
    | And (Expression a) (Expression a)
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

class Expr e where
    true, false :: e
    var :: String -> e
    not :: e -> e
    or, and :: e -> e -> e

instance Expr (Expression Explicit) where
    true = Literal True
    false = Literal False
    var = Variable
    not = Not
    or = Or
    and = And

eitherOrder :: (e -> e -> e)
            -> (e -> e -> Maybe e)
            -> e -> e -> e
eitherOrder fExplicit fSimplified x y = fromMaybe
    (fExplicit x y)
    (fSimplified x y <|> fSimplified y x)

instance Expr (Expression Simplified) where
    true = Literal True
    false = Literal False
    var = Variable

    not (Literal True) = false
    not (Literal False) = true
    not (Not x) = x
    not x = Not x

    or = eitherOrder Or go where
        go (Literal True) _ = Just true
        go (Literal False) x = Just x
        go (Variable x) (Variable y) | x == y = Just (var x)
        go (Variable x) (Not (Variable y)) | x == y = Just true
        go _ _ = Nothing

    and = eitherOrder And go where
        go (Literal True) x = Just x
        go (Literal False) _ = Just false
        go (Variable x) (Variable y) | x == y = Just (var x)
        go (Variable x) (Not (Variable y)) | x == y = Just false
        go _ _ = Nothing
```

Now in ghci we can do more complicated simplifications, like:

```
> and (not (not (var "x"))) (var "x") :: Expression Simplified
Variable "x"
```

And even though we only wrote one order of the rewrite rule, both orders work properly:

```
> and (not (var "x")) (var "x") :: Expression Simplified
Literal False
> and (var "x") (not (var "x")) :: Expression Simplified
Literal False
```

Comment: In my case, the choice of whether to simplify or not will be made before constructing the terms, so this will play out very nicely. If I could, I would give you another +1 just for the way symmetry is handled!

Answer (score 13):

Basically the problem is that you have to write out `simplify` of the subexpressions in each clause, over and over again. It would be better to first get all the subexpressions done before even considering laws involving the top-level operator. One simple way is to add an auxiliary version of `simplify`, that doesn't recurse down:

```
simplify :: Expression -> Expression
simplify (Literal b) = Literal b
simplify (Variable s) = Variable s
simplify (Not e) = simplify' . Not $ simplify e
simplify (And a b) = simplify' $ And (simplify a) (simplify b)
simplify (Or a b) = simplify' $ Or (simplify a) (simplify b)

simplify' :: Expression -> Expression
simplify' (Not (Literal b)) = Literal $ not b
simplify' (And (Literal False) _) = Literal False
...
```

With the only small amount of operations you have in booleans, this is probably the most sensible approach. However with more operations, the duplication in `simplify` might still be worth to avoid. To that end, you can conflate the unary and binary operations to a common constructor:

```
data Expression 
    = Literal Bool 
    | Variable String
    | BoolPrefix BoolPrefix Expression 
    | BoolInfix BoolInfix Expression Expression 
    deriving Eq

data BoolPrefix = Negation
data BoolInfix  = AndOp | OrOp
```

and then you have just

```
simplify (Literal b) = Literal b
simplify (Variable s) = Variable s
simplify (BoolPrefix bpf e) = simplify' . BoolPrefix bpf $ simplify e
simplify (BoolInfix bifx a b) = simplify' $ BoolInfix bifx (simplify a) (simplify b)
```

Obviously this makes `simplify'` more awkward though, so perhaps not such a good idea. You can however get around this syntactical overhead by defining specialised [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern Not :: Expression -> Expression
pattern Not x = BoolPrefix Negation x

infixr 3 :∧
pattern (:∧) :: Expression -> Expression -> Expression
pattern a:∧b = BoolInfix AndOp a b

infixr 2 :∨
pattern (:∨) :: Expression -> Expression -> Expression
pattern a:∨b = BoolInfix OrOp a b
```

For that matter, perhaps also

```
pattern F, T :: Expression
pattern F = Literal False
pattern T = Literal True
```

With that, you can then write

```
simplify' :: Expression -> Expression
simplify' (Not (Literal b)) = Literal $ not b
simplify' (F :∧ _) = F
simplify' (_ :∧ F) = F
simplify' (T :∨ _) = T
simplify' (a :∧ Not b) | a==b  = T
...
```

I should add a caveat though: [when I tried something similar to those pattern synonyms, not for booleans but affine mappings, it made the compiler *extremely slow*](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/manifolds/commit/c1d6b174e87c8e3ba4363462eb8de58aedfe79cc). (Also, GHC-7.10 didn't yet support polymorphic pattern synonyms yet; this has changed quite a bit as of now.)

---

Note also that all this will not generally yield the simplest possible form – 
for that, you'd need to find the fixed point of `simplify`.

Comment: So Pattern Synonyms are a thing, nice! Especially for the repetitive ```Literal True```, this is quite nice. The only thing that still bothers me is the fact that some patterns have to be repeated (both sides of an And can be false), but maybe I can use some TemplateHaskell magic. Never worked with that one, gonna be fun!

Comment: Well, you could catch that all with a `simplify' (BoolInfix ifx a b) = simplify' (BoolInfix ifx b a)` clause; however then you'll run into an infinite loop if no rule fires...

Comment: That also won't work for non-commutative operators such as implication.

Answer (score 6):

I think Einstein said, "Simplify as much as possible, but no more." You have yourself a complicated datatype, and a correspondingly complicated concept, so I assume any technique can only be so much cleaner for the problem at hand.

That said, the first option is to use instead a case structure.

```
simplify x = case x of
   Literal _  -> x
   Variable _ -> x
   Not e      -> simplifyNot $ simplify e
   ...
   where
     sharedFunc1 = ...
     sharedFunc2 = ...
```

This has the added benefit of including shared functions which will be usable by all cases but not at the top level namespace. I also like how the cases are freed of their parenthesis. (Also note that in the first two cases i just return the original term, not creating a new one). I often use this sort of structure to just break out other simplify functions, as in the case of `Not`.

This problem in particular may lend itself to basing `Expression` on an underlying functor, so that you may `fmap` a simplification of the subexpressions and then perform the specific combinations of the given case. It will look something like the following:

```
simplify :: Expression' -> Expression'
simplify = Exp . reduce . fmap simplify . unExp
```

The steps in this are unwrapping `Expression'` into the underlying functor representation, mapping the simplification on the underlying term, and then reducing that simplification and wrapping back up into the new `Expression'`

```
{-# Language DeriveFunctor #-}

newtype Expression' = Exp { unExp :: ExpressionF Expression' }

data ExpressionF e
  = Literal Bool 
  | Variable String
  | Not e 
  | Or e e
  | And e e
  deriving (Eq,Functor)
```

Now, I have pushed the complexity off into the `reduce` function, which is only a little less complex because it doesn't have to worry about first reducing the subterm. But it will now contain solely the business logic of combining one term with another.

This may or may not be a good technique for you, but it may make some enhancements easier. For instance, if it is possible to form invalid expressions in your language, you could simplify that with `Maybe` valued failures.

```
simplifyMb :: Expression' -> Maybe Expression'
simplifyMb = fmap Exp . reduceMb <=< traverse simplifyMb . unExp
```

Here, `traverse` will apply `simplfyMb` to the subterms of the `ExpressionF`, resulting in an expression of `Maybe` subterms, `ExpressionF (Maybe Expression')`, and then if any subterms are `Nothing`, it will return `Nothing`, if all are `Just x`, it will return `Just (e::ExpressionF Expression')`. Traverse isn't actually separated into distinct phases like that, but it's easier to explain as if it were. Also note, you will need language pragmas for DeriveTraversable and DeriveFoldable, as well as deriving statements on the `ExpressionF` data type.

The downside? Well, for one the dirt of your code will then lie in a bunch of `Exp` wrappers everywhere. Consider the application of `simplfyMb` of the simple term below:

```
simplifyMb (Exp $ Not (Exp $ Literal True))
```

It's also a lot to get a head around, but if you understand `traverse` and `fmap` pattern above, you can reuse it in lots of places, so that's good. I also believe defining simplify in that way makes it more robust to whatever the specific `ExpressionF` constructions may turn into. It doesn't mention them so the deep simplification will be unaffected by refactors. The reduce function on the other hand will be.

Comment: Nice. Maybe you could state that the second approach is essentially using `cata` from recursion-schemes, so to provide a pointer.

Comment: This really is a refreshing approach, which should come naturally as an Expression is just a tree ready to be traversed. The dirt, as you called it, does bother me though... spreading ```Exp``` around everywhere is something I'd rather not do.

Comment: @PhilippKiener, the usual answer to cleaning that up in recent GHC versions is to name the `ExpressionF` constructors with `F`s at the ends and use pattern synonyms to define the `Expression'` "constructors". In this case, those are simple bidirectional pattern synonyms. For example: `pattern And :: Expression' -> Expression' -> Expression'; pattern And a b = Exp (AndF a b)`.

Comment: @chi, well, it looks like I know what I'll be learning more about for the rest of the afternoon/week. Thanks for the pointer. If you would like to add, please be my guest.

Comment: Well, these are a couple of interesting suggestions, but IMO the functor instance doesn't make sense. You're abusing the `Functor`/`Traversable` interface to express a (pretty uncanonical) higher-order function that might better just be done as a simple private helper `traverseSubexprs :: Applicative a => (Expression -> a Expression) -> Expression -> a Expression`. An actual functor should be able to sensibly, _canonically_ contain _any_ type (or at least any type from some well-specified class, as the various constrained-category libraries allow), but here, only `Expression` makes any sense.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, how so? This is a pretty common approach. Why do only sibexpressions of the same type make sense to you?

Comment: @dfeuer well, they aren't really subexpressions if their type isn't `Expression`...

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I translated the `Expression` term into the fixed point of an underlying base functor, see recursion-schemes package for more examples (thanks @chi). This is pretty well studied, I can't remember where I saw it spelled out most clearly, but McBride's "Clowns [..] Jokers [..]" seems to have left an effect on me. I remember reading that and getting a sense of how `deriving(Generic)` works. Anyway, we're interested in the fixed point of that functor, not the functor itself. The decomposition is useful because functors are composable, enabling generic deriving type machinery.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I made an edit to make my explanation more precise. Previously i said make `Expression` into a functor, which is not what i meant and which did warrant your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Carrying on with your `Binary Op Expression Expression` idea, we could have the datatype:

```
data Expression
    = Literal Bool
    | Variable String
    | Not Expression
    | Binary Op Expression Expression
    deriving Eq

data Op = Or | And deriving Eq
```

And an auxiliary function

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

simplifyBinary  :: Op -> Expression -> Expression -> Expression
simplifyBinary  binop (simplify -> leftexp) (simplify -> rightexp) =
    case oneway binop leftexp rightexp ++ oneway binop rightexp leftexp of
        simplified : _ -> simplified
        []             -> Binary binop leftexp rightexp
  where
    oneway :: Op -> Expression -> Expression -> [Expression]
    oneway And (Literal False) _ = [Literal False]
    oneway Or  (Literal True)  _ = [Literal True]
    -- more cases here
    oneway _   _               _ = []
```

The idea is that you would put the simplification cases in `oneway` and then `simplifyBinary` would take care of reversing the arguments, to avoid having to write the symmetric cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a generic simplifier for all binary operations:

```
simplifyBinWith :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -- the boolean operation
                -> (Expression -> Expression -> Expression) -- the constructor
                -> Expression -> Expression -- the two operands
                -> Expression) -- the simplified result
simplifyBinWith op cons a b = case (simplify a, simplify b) of
    (Literal x, Literal y) -> Literal (op x y)
    (Literal x, b')        -> tryAll (x `op`) b'
    (a',        Literal y) -> tryAll (`op` y) a'
    (a',        b')        -> cons a' b'
  where
    tryAll f term = case (f True, f False) of -- what would f do if term was true of false
      (True,  True)  -> Literal True
      (True,  False) -> term
      (False, True)  -> Not term
      (False, False) -> Literal False
```

That way, your `simplify` function would become

```
simplify :: Expression -> Expression
simplify (Not e)   = case simplify e of
    (Literal b) -> Literal (not b)
    e'          -> Not e'
simplify (And a b) = simplifyBinWith (&&) And a b
simplify (Or a b)  = simplifyBinWith (||) Or a b
simplify t         = t
```

and could be easily extended to more binary operations. It would also work well with the `Binary Op Expression Expression` idea, you'd pass `Op` instead of an `Expression` constructor to `simplifyBinWith` and the pattern in `simplify` could be generalised:

```
simplify :: Expression -> Expression
simplify (Not e)         = case simplify e of
    (Literal b) -> Literal (not b)
    e'          -> Not e'
simplify (Binary op a b) = simplifyBinWith (case op of
    And -> (&&)
    Or -> (||)
    Xor -> (/=)
    Implies -> (<=)
    Equals -> (==)
    …
  ) op a b
simplify t               = t
  where
    simplifyBinWith f op a b = case (simplify a, simplify b) of
      (Literal x, Literal y) -> Literal (f x y)
      …
      (a',        b')        -> Binary op a' b'
```