# A Function which Simplifying Boolean Expressions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, boolean

I am dealing with the following grammar, which I have implemented in the form of a Haskell `data` type.

```
    bool ::=   tt   |   ff   |   bool ∧ bool   |   var        
    var  ::=   letter{letter|digit}*
```

My question is, I would like to write a function `simplify :: bool → bool` which simplifies boolean expressions in the usual way (while doing nothing to variables). For example, I would like

```
    simplify(tt ∧ ff) = ff
    simplify(tt ∧ x) =  x
    simplify(x ∧ (y ∧ z)) = x ∧ y ∧ z
```

where the letters *x*, *y* and *z* are denoting variables (`var`).

I feel that the natural definition is the following (pseudocode with pattern matching)

```
    simplify(tt) = tt
    simplify(ff) = ff
    simplify(x)  = x
    simplify(tt ∧ b) = simplify(b)
    simplify(b ∧ tt) = simplify(b)
    simplify(b₁ ∧ b₂) = simplify(b₁) ∧ simplify(b₂)                (†)
```

where *b*, *b₁* and *b₂* denote *bool*s, and *x* denotes a *var*.

This definition works fine for all the given examples above. The problem is with expressions such as `(tt ∧ tt) ∧ (tt ∧ tt)`. Indeed, applying the definition, we have

```
    simplify((tt ∧ tt) ∧ (tt ∧ tt)) = simplify(tt ∧ tt) ∧ simplify(tt ∧ tt) 
                                    = simplify(tt) ∧ simplify(tt) 
                                    = tt ∧ tt
```

which we should be able to further simplify as simply `tt`.

Thus maybe changing the definition line `(†)` to

```
    simplify(b₁ ∧ b₂) = simplify(simplify(b₁) ∧ simplify(b₂))
```

will solve the problem, since it simplifies the results of conjunctions, which does actually work! But then it breaks when we have variables (it goes into an infinite loop in fact):

```
    simplify(x ∧ y) = simplify(simplify(x) ∧ simplify(y))   
                    = simplify(x ∧ y)       
                    = ...
```

Thus my idea was to retain the old definition, but then actually simplify by finding fixed points. Indeed, the function `simplify' :: bool → bool` written in Haskell below, behaves as desired:

```haskell
simplify' :: BoolExpr -> BoolExpr
simplify' f 
    | (simplify f) == f   = f
    | otherwise           = simplify' (simplify f)
```

It just feels like an inelegant solution to the problem, since it keeps repeatedly running a function which *feels like*, if defined correctly, needs to be run only once. I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You might also like [Cleaner Alternative to Extensive Pattern Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45486842/791604).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> simplify(b₁ ∧ b₂) = simplify(simplify(b₁) ∧ simplify(b₂))
> ```
>
> will solve the problem, since it simplifies the results of conjunctions, which does actually work! But then it breaks when we have variables (it goes into an infinite loop in fact):

Do you really want to recurse over `simplify(b₁) ∧ simplify(b₂)`? Maybe you want to `simplify(b₁)` and `simplify(b₂)` and then simply operate them. As in,

```
data B = T | F | V | B :&: B deriving Show

s :: B -> B
s T = T
s F = F
s V = V
s (b1 :&: b2) = opAND (s b1) (s b2) 

opAND F _ = F
opAND _ F = F 
opAND T b = b
opAND b T = b
opAND a b = a :&: b
```

The simplify function `s` essentially folds your syntax tree, at each step guaranteeing that you preserve the property that the simplified expression is either atomic, or contains no occurrences of neither `F` nor `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue is that you're doing your `simplify(tt ∧ b)` test on unsimplified expressions.

The logic you're looking for would be more like:

```
simplify(a ^ b) | simplify(a) == tt = simplify b
```

which can be efficiently implemented by simplifying both *before* the simplifying pattern match:

```
simplify(b₁ ∧ b₂) =
  case (simplify(b₁), simplify(b₂)) of
    (tt, x) -> x
    (x, tt) -> x
    ...
```