# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets). I'm making a function that gets rid of multiplicatoin by 1 and add by 1 and 0

Tags: haskell

So I am doing a course on programming languages and I have this code written but for some reason I get the error mentioned in the title. I really don't know what is going on here. A bit of help would be greatly appreciated. The function is not done yet but I wanted to understand this type of mistake before I tackle the rest of the code.

```hs
data Exp = Enum Int -- Une constante
        | Eplus Exp Exp -- e1 + e2
        | Etimes Exp Exp -- e1 * e2


optimize::Exp->Exp
optimize expr = 
    if (expr == Eplus (Enum 0) (Enum x)) || (expr == Eplus (Enum x) (Enum 0))  then optimize (Enum x)

Error:

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets).
```

Comment: The error message says "Possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets".  Did you check for those?  The error message is already trying pretty hard to tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Every `if` in Haskell requires an `else`.

Comment: [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45486842/791604)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the syntax error (which David Young identified as a missing `else` clause), you’re using an variable `x` which hasn’t been defined. Are you trying to do pattern matching? Some helpful resources for understanding pattern matching are [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) and [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html).